# Creating nodes from a list (UNWIND) in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

After unwinding a json file I am getting a list of string as output which needs to be created as node.

Query which returns a list of urls(string):-

```
WITH {json} AS document
UNWIND document.log.entries AS API
UNWIND API.request.url as a
RETURN a
```

Tried with FOREACH to create nodes with the above query list but  getting exceptions.

```
FOREACH (n IN nodes(a) | CREATE (n))
```

but getting exception. 
need help with query .

Comment: can you show complete query that you are using

Comment: please give us sample json in your output. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the value of `a` is a URL string, then:

- `NODES(a)` would not work since the argument to `NODES()` must be a [path](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/patterns/#cypher-pattern-related-nodes).
- Also, `FOREACH` is not even needed, since `a` is a scalar value (a string), not a list.

Here is an example of creating nodes containing the URL string:

```
WITH $json AS document
UNWIND document.log.entries AS API
UNWIND API.request.url as a
CREATE (f:Foo {url: a});
```

*The above query also uses `$json` instead of the deprecated `{json}` syntax.*

Alternatively, if you removed the last `UNWIND` clause, here is how you could use `FOREACH`:

```
WITH $json AS document
UNWIND document.log.entries AS API
FOREACH(a IN API.request.url | CREATE (f:Foo {url: a}));
```